# Sometimes can get text but sometimes show "Unable to find element with selector"

Tags: c#, jquery, css, fluentautomation

I use `var n = I.Find(("#CSS_path");` to find a element and click it.I want to compare the text inside element.So I tried to use `var nt = n.Element.Text;` and `string name = n.Element.ToString();` to get the text inside.`ToString()` can't get it. So I use `n.Element.Text`.But it sometimes can get the text, sometimes show the wrong "Unable to find element with selector".And I also tried to use `var nt = n.Element.Text; string name = nt.ToString();`.But it still has the same problem.
By the way, n.element is not null.It has the right text that I want to compare.

Why this would happen?Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience,Sometimes when the page keep refreshing with ajax,it may occur.